# UIButton stretches in landscape mode

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

In my app i've two `UIButton` on top. The buttons were created via storyboard

I've added "suggested constraints" and a fixed width for both.

In portrait mode the view is
[image]

that is what i want. If i rotate device, landscape mode is
[image]

So the `DEL DB` button stretches itself, also if it has fixed width. Why?

The constraints are these
[image]

where `Apps Scroll View` is under `DEL DB` button and `Apps List` is under `SEND DB` button. They split the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Delete Button.centerX` is anchored to `Apps Scroll View.centerX` - remove that constraint and it should work as you expect (it's the 8th constraint in the list on your picture.